# Python Flask-RESTful method delete error - "message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL."

Tags: python, api, flask, url, flask-restful

What could be the problem?

I have a function that deletes a record from the database by id. Function separately from api works.

```py
def delete_student(student_id: int):
    del_student = db.session.query(Student).filter_by(id=student_id).one()
    db.session.delete(del_student)
    return db.session.commit()
```

But when i use this function via api i get error: {"response": {"message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL."}}

```py
class AddDeleteStudent(Resource):
    def delete(self, user_id):
        return delete_student(user_id)

api.add_resource(AddDeleteStudent, '/api/v1/students/<int:user_id>')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't add code showing how you're invoking the API.

If you're using curl and you don't specify the method in the call, I believe it defaults to a `get` and you don't have a `get` defined for your API.

To do a delete, you have to do something like

`curl <your_url> -X DELETE -v`

See the [documentation](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-api) for how to invoke and specify your method (in this case 'delete')